# How can I create any Alarm like for Everyday another job like a Reminder?

Tags: android, calendar, task, scheduled-tasks, alarmmanager

I want to create a App like a Daily alarm, for my Maps app. I have to Drive for Mondays at 09:00 am to XXX Street 7, For Tuesday 10:00 am to YYY Street 8, also every Monday 9 uhr I have to get a Alarm and Google Maps will be opened, Address will be navigated. I need only the code for Alarm for days. Intent I can make myself.

Algorithm:
If Date Monday- Clock 09 am- Ring+Google Maps Address Navigation
If Date Tuesday Clock 10 Am Ring+Google Maps Address Navigation

I tried with Scheduled Tasks but they are only for Every day same Time

Comment: What is the logic to scheduling of time??

Comment: I have integrate this code in app otherwise , I could use the Google reminder or other apps.This is for my weekly plan.